# Terramar Packages: GitLab 8.3.2 webhooks fail

Tags: composer-php, gitlab

Using GitLab 8.3.2 all webhooks fail with message `Hook execution failed: Accepted`

The command line satis:build fails with

```
[Composer\Json\JsonValidationException]
The json config file does not match the expected JSON schema
```

satis.json is

```
{
    "output-dir": "\/var\/www\/packages\/web",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.example.com:xxx\/xxx.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.example.com:xxx\/xxx-ui-kit.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.example.com:xxx\/xxx2.git"
        }
    ],
    "output-html": false,
    "require-dependencies": true,
    "require-dev-dependencies": true
}
```

Could anybody point out, where the problem stems from? I am not quite sure whether this is a issue with packages.

Comment: From looking at [the JSON schema](https://github.com/composer/satis/blob/master/res/satis-schema.json) it seems that you are missing the `name` and `homepage` properties.

Comment: I was about to comment that @xabbuh, but is seems the schema we referenced should be unrelated. For the sake of it, could you try that, @Bonscho?

Comment: You are damn right son. The problem is that the **satis.json** is validated as **composer.json** for whatever reason. So the mandatory members `name` and `homepage` are missing. After adding these two members manually to the satis.json the `satis:build` call is successful.

Comment: The JSON schema file I linked is not related to Composer but is for Satis (it was only added recently IIRC which be the reason why you didn't have the error before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, this is either

- an issue related to composer (as it should not validate a satis config file as a composer file) or
- related to whatever program generates the config file you cited. In this case, it should rather generate acceptable config files.

For now, you can manually make the json comply to the schema and hope for fixes in any of the two related projects - and/or file issues with them.

Comment: I came down with this beeing two different problems.

At first the satis.json is validated against a composer.json validator by the satis lib used by Terramar Packages for whatever reason.

At second GitLab does not accept HTTP status 202 a valid successful response to webhooks but should do.